# What's the tax on a hobby crop income?

Tags: taxes, income-tax, income, california, land

Say I harvest crop as a hobby on my land, and it's less than an acre. What's the tax on the crop income?

Comment: http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/54056/whats-the-tax-on-a-hobby-orchard

Comment: Duplicate of "What's the tax on a hobby orchard"